# Как запросить ссылку на видеофайл в flashplayer'е?

Tags: html, python, google-chrome, видео, flash-player

Есть видео на сайте внутри флешплеера. Можно ли на пайтон или вручную в хром получить ссылку к этому видеофайлу, чтобы скачать его?

Comment: Пробовали правый клик -> Посмотреть код?

Comment: Возможно, поможет https://superuser.com/questions/114196/how-to-find-the-stream-behind-a-flash-player

Comment: @pank пробовал, конечно, только смысл какой? Это же flash

Comment: посмотрите какие сетевые соединения chrome устанавливает в инструментах разработчика или [поддерживает ли youtube-dl ваш сайт](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html)

Comment: @carapuz а это хорошая идея. Попробовал посмотреть какие url'ы появляются при проигрывании видео через chrome://net-internals/#events, но прямой ссылки я так и не нашёл. Только ссылки вида **http://i546.hotcloud.org/vod/vod/d6/bd/000000000002bdd6_4_6_8_01.smil/media_b500000.abst/Seg1-Frag1** до **FragN** (**возможно, что до *SegN-FragN***) и ещё ссылку на манифест **http://i546.hotcloud.org/vod/vod/d6/bd/000000000002bdd6_4_6_8_01.smil/manifest.f4m** странного расширения

Comment: Проблема решена, предлагаю всем ознакомиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема разрешилась с помощью сервиса [ShowMyCode](http://www.showmycode.com/), который был недоступен некоторое время.

Я поковырялся в коде и нашёл там несколько ссылок с указанием какая ссылка за какое качество отвечает.

Среди них были ссылки на всякие манифесты, были массивы из ссылок на сторонние ресурсы (судя по всему, рандомная реклама) и т.д.

Далее я просто воспользовался своим скриптом для [скачивания файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652896/243273)

Но можно и просто вручную открывать ссылку в браузере и нажимать на `ПКМ->сохранить как`.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, ну некоторые ссылки можно увидеть используя средства разработчика Google Chrome, например:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ9CL.png

А далее с помощью любой подходящей библиотеки Python забрать видео по прямой ссылке(например, urllib2).

Comment: Видео находится в flash player'е. Просмотреть исходный код страницы я могу, мало того, мне это нужно, но это мне никак не поможет, чтобы достать ссылку на видео

Comment: В исходном коде находится относительный адрес на файл с видео, разве нет?

Comment: нет, конечно. Это же flash, а не html

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, я решил проблему. Может заинтересует