# Проверка расширений при скачивании файла, Python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, загрузка

Всем доброго времени суток, из за недостаточного набора знаний приходится добирать их.

Есть ссылка https://v3bl.goszakup.gov.kz/files/download_file/27503075/

Она никуда не переадресовывает, а сразу идёт скачивание файлов.

При скачивании - полный файлы разные (либо .pdf либо .html).

Мне нужно до скачивания узнать какое расширение имеет файл и какое имя, и присвоить это при скачивании.

Или не заморачиваться и скачать всё как есть, как можно реализовать?
По ссылкам может быть файл либо .pdf либо .html, нужно что бы скрипт отличал и хотя бы при скачивании верно ставил расширение.

Наброски:

```
address = 'https://v3bl.goszakup.gov.kz/files/download_file/27503075/'
directory = "C:\\temp"
response = requests.get(address, directory, verify=False, stream=True, headers={'user-agent': 'firefox', 'Accept': '*/*'})
with open('ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА_И_РАСШИРЕНИЕ', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(stream.read())
```

Comment: берите из http-заголовка: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="auction_pi_1304039.html"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить имя файла, указанное в `Content-Disposition` http заголовке, имея `response` объект, возвращаемый из `requests.get()`, можно использовать [`rfc6266-parser` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc6266-parser/) (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil
import sys
import requests  # $ pip install requests
import rfc6266_parser as rfc6266  # $ pip install rfc6266-parser

# make http request
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()

# get filename from Content-Disposition http header
filename = rfc6266.parse_requests_response(r).filename_unsafe
if not filename.endswith(('.pdf', '.html')):
    sys.exit('abort downloading: unknown file extension: %r' % (filename,))

# download file
r.raw.decode_content = True  # handle gzipped responses
with open(os.path.basename(filename), 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, file)
```

Comment: Благодарю, ваша часть скрипта показалась мне наиболее подходящей и понятной.

Comment: Не могу подключить директорию, всё в корень качает...

`dir_file = 'D:\temp\goszakup_win_download'
                r = requests.get(address, verify=False, stream=True, headers={'user-agent': 'firefox'})`

Comment: @Larvis: к чему вы `requests.get()` указали не ясно (этот вызов никаких файлов не сохраняет). Код в моём ответе качает всегда в [текущую рабочую директорию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044) (следует из использования `os.path.basename()`). Чтобы свою директорию указать, вы можете использовать `os.path.join(ваша_директория, os.path.basename(filename))`. (если это не ясно, то задайте отдельный вопрос: "как добавить директорию к имени файла в Питоне")

Comment: @jfs а кто-то требовал от меня добавить os.path.join() в вопросе с изображениями в директории...) А сам сейчас так же реагирует: если не ясно как это реализовать - задавайте другой вопрос)

Comment: @KitScribe: не путайте  исправление *сломанного* кода (ваш случай) и добавление *новой* функциональности в этом случае (сохранение в другую директорию).

Comment: @jfs ну не знаю. Не считаю свой код сломанным. Если кому-то не ясно очевидное, возможно, ему не стоит заниматься программированием?

Answer (score 0):

Написал функцию для скачивания файлов, проверьте

```
import requests
import os


def download_file(url, path, verify=True, filename=None, postfix=None):
    """
    download_file(url, path, filename=None, verify=True, postfix=None)

    Download file from url to path with filename. If postfix is not None and \
    file does not end with postfix, abort download.

    Postfix can be only str or tuple. Verify needs for SSL checking.

    If filename is None function will automatically add filename in attachment \
    or the last slashed string

    If download complete - return True, else - print exception and return False
    """
    try:
        res = r.get(url, stream=True, verify=verify)

        if res.status_code == 200:
            if filename is None:
                try:
                    match = re.search(r'filename="(.+)"', res.headers['Content-Disposition'])

                    if match:
                        filename = match.group(1)

                    else:
                        filename = url.split('/')

                        if len(filename[-1]) != 0:
                            filename = filename[-1]
                        else:
                            filename = filename[-2]

                except:
                    filename = url.split('/')

                    if len(filename[-1]) != 0:
                        filename = filename[-1]
                    else:
                        filename = filename[-2]

            if postfix is not None:
                if not filename.endswith(postfix):
                    print('Wrong file extension. Abort download')
                    return False

            with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as f:
                for bytes_chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
                    if bytes_chunk:
                        f.write(bytes_chunk)

            return True

        else:
            print('Connection error with', url)
            return False

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

Дополнил ответ функцией:

```
def download_or_die(url, path, filename=None, postfix=None):
    '''
    download_or_die(url, path, filename=None,l postfix=None)
    Download file anyway if it possible with download_file() function
    Return the result value: success - True, failure - False
    '''
    for i in range(1, -1, -1):
        result = download_file(url, path, bool(i), filename, postfix)
        if result:
            break

    return result
```

Будет пытаться скачать, перебирая возможные варианты проверки сертификата. Если файл невозможно скачать, вернёт False

Обе функции отлично справляются с файлами:

[Ваш html файл](https://v3bl.goszakup.gov.kz/files/download_file/27503075/) с битой кодировкой

[Изображение средних размеров](https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/003/353/597/large/john-dervishi-munch.jpg)

[PDF файл](http://www.shellgreenier.com/MGreenier-Resume.pdf)

Comment: У вас тут только в html, а нужно что бы он отличал в каком формате скачивать.
И ещё кодировка сбилась.

Comment: @Larvis прочтите документацию к функции: если имя не указано, то будет взято имя после последнего, либо после предпоследнего слеша (если после последнего слеша пусто)ъ. Но так как у вас нет расширения у файла, то я указал напрямую имя с расширением, чтобы потом не переименовывать. А кодировка у вас такая и была в файле. Попробуйте вручную скачать и открыть файл.

Comment: @Larvis но задача интересная. Я попробую автоматически узнать имя и расширение файла, который скачивается и если получится, обновлю ответ и сообщу об этом в комментарии

Comment: @Larvis решил, ответ обновил

Comment: @Larvis теперь проверка осуществляется

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой набросок:

```
import re
import os

import requests


def download_file(url: str, dir_path: str = None):
    rs = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    match = re.search('filename="(.+)"', rs.headers['Content-Disposition'])
    if match:
        file_name = match.group(1)
        if not dir_path:
            dir_path = os.getcwd()

        os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

        print('Download {} in {}'.format(file_name, dir_path))

        file_name = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(rs.content)
```

Использование:

```
url = 'https://v3bl.goszakup.gov.kz/files/download_file/27503075/' 
    
# Текущая папка (нужно быть осторожнее, от того из какой папки был
# запущен интерпретатор будет зависеть куда сохранит, 
# поэтому лучше указывать папку сохранения)
download_file(url)
    
# На С:/
download_file(url, 'C:/')
    
# На С:/1/2/3, если папок нет, скрипт их создаст
download_file(url, 'C:/1/2/3')
```